# Tuleap - Configure rights to change tracker reports

Tags: report, config, rights, tracker, tuleap

In a tracker you can select the report columns and the search criteria and save them as a personal report. (with the option to make the personal report public later on)

It appears that to do this, you need to be a tracker admin. The criteria/column buttons do not appear for a new user with basic rights.

What we would like to do is to allow any tracker user to change columns and search criteria according to his individiual needs and save his own, personal reports.
But without making him a full tracker admin with access to the tracker admin page where everything can be changed and potentially damaged.

Is there a way to configure Tuleap for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all users can add their own colums and criteria

But they need to create a personal report first (for instance with a "Save as")